# Passing control as parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to pass a control's id to a javascript function that adds the value of it(the control which is a textbox) to a listbox but apparently I am not getting it right, can someone please correct me.

Thanks.

```
<input type="button" ID="btnAddtoLstBox" value="" title="Add this to the list" onclick="javascript:addToList(document.getElementById(btnAddtoLstBox));"
class="ui-icon ui-icon-refresh ui-corner-all" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; background-position: -64px 80px"  />

  // scripts to add list items
        function addToList(varTxtBox) {

                 // get the list box
                var lb = document.getElementById("uilstMemTypeTier");

                // get the text to add
                var toAdd = varTxtBox.value;

                if (toAdd == "") return false;

                // look for the delimiter string. if found, alert and do nothing
                if (toAdd.indexOf(delim) != -1) {
                    alert("The value to add to the list cannot contain the text \"" + delim + "\" as it is used as the delimiter string.");
                    return false;
                }

                // check if the value is already in the list box
                for (i = 0; i < lb.length; i++) {
                    if (toAdd == lb.options[i].value) {
                        alert("The text you tried to add is already in the list box.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // add it to the hidden field
                document.getElementById("<%=uihdnlistBasedFieldsListItems.ClientID%>").value += toAdd + delim;

                // create an option and add it to the end of the listbox
                lb.options[lb.length] = new Option(toAdd, toAdd);

                // clear the textfield and focus it
                varTxtBox.value = "";
                varTxtBox.focus();
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Which bit isn't working?

Comment: Also, is `delim` variable in enclosing scope and defined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `onclick="javascript:addToList(document.getElementById(btnAddtoLstBox));"` to `onclick="addToList(document.getElementById('btnAddtoLstBox'));"`  or `onclick="addToList(this);"`

Comment: what about for <%=id.ClientID%> ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using control event handler you can provide `this` and it be control:

```
 onclick="addToList(this)"
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/ARBHj/

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in following way-

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="div1" style="height:100px; width:192px; background-color:red;">

</div>
<br />
<div id="div2" style="height:100px; width:192px; background-color:green; display:block">

</div>
<br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Change color" id="btnColor" OnClientClick="javascript:return changeColor();"/>
    <asp:Button Text="Hide 1st" runat="server" ID="btnHide1st" OnClientClick="javascript:return hideDiv('div1');"/>
    <asp:Button Text="Hide 2nd" runat="server" id="btnHide2nd" OnClientClick="javascript:return hideDiv('div2');"/>
</form>
```

Hope this may have helped you.